# How to use custom signals in GObject?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject, gobject

I want to make a program with a TreeView widget and a few items in it which could exchange data through emitting and catching a signal which I called `incr`.

I created 10 tree items, connected `incr` signal to each of them. Now if I emit `incr` signal from one of those, why don't the other 9 receive it?

Why does only the emitter object catches signals emitted by itself?

Here is a sample program demonstrating this problem:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject


class TreeItem(GObject.GObject):
    __gsignals__ = {
        'incr': (GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, GObject.TYPE_NONE, ())
    }

    def __init__(self, title):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)
        self.title = title

    def do_incr(self):
        print('It works!')

GObject.type_register(TreeItem)


class Application(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        self.connect('destroy', self.__on_destroy)
        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        button = Gtk.Button('emit signal')
        button.connect('clicked', self.__on_button_clicked)
        vbox.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)

        list_store = Gtk.ListStore(GObject.GObject)
        text_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        tree_column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(None, text_renderer)
        self.__tree_view = Gtk.TreeView(list_store)
        self.__tree_view.append_column(tree_column)
        tree_column.set_cell_data_func(text_renderer, self.__populate_tree)
        vbox.pack_start(self.__tree_view, True, True, 0)
        self.add(vbox)

        self.show_all()

        for i in range(10):
            item = TreeItem(str(i))
            item.connect('incr', self.__on_incr)
            list_store.append((item,))

    def __on_incr(self, item):
        item.title = str(int(item.title) + 1)
        self.__tree_view.queue_draw()

    def __on_button_clicked(self, e):
        selected_item = self.get_selected_item()
        if selected_item:
            selected_item.emit('incr')

    def get_selected_item(self):
        selection = self.__tree_view.get_selection()
        if selection:
            model, iter_ = selection.get_selected()
            return model.get_value(iter_, 0)

    def __populate_tree(self, column, cell, model, iter_, user_data):
        item = model.get_value(iter_, 0)
        cell.set_property('text', item.title)

    def __on_destroy(self, e):
        Gtk.main_quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: You do not emit the signal anywhere in the above code. And when you emit a signal, other objects of the same type do not get a notification; they have to connect to every other object's signal for that to work. For what it's worth, if you want the GtkTreeView to update every time the `do_incr` signal is called, you're probably better off with a custom GtkTreeModel subclass; it has a `changed` signal which you emit to notify the GtkTreeView that an object has changed.

Comment: @andlabs I'm emitting signal in __on_button_clicked(). All items are connected to callback function by connect().

Answer (score 0):

> I created 10 tree items, connected 'incr' signal to each of them and now if I emit 'incr' signal from one of those why the rest of 9 cant receive it?

You are connecting your TreeItems's to your Application so as expected when a TreeItem emits the signal your Application receives it. Your TreeItem's are not connected to anything so they receive nothing. I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish where you would want that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant parts are here:

```python
    [...]
    for i in range(10):
        item = TreeItem(str(i))
        item.connect('incr', self.__on_incr)
        list_store.append((item,))
```

You connect every item to a signal, and then:

```python
def __on_button_clicked(self, e):
    selected_item = self.get_selected_item()
    if selected_item:
        selected_item.emit('incr')
```

It is emitting the signal to **selected_item** only, because that is the only one that is being emitting.

That fact that every item is connected to the same method does not imply that when the signal is emitted, all of items will be called. The signal is emitted per object, as you did in `selected_item.emit('incr')` (you are telling: for this `selected_item`, please emit the signal `incr`). The signal for the other item were never emitted.